# Sumifs with OR AND

Tags: excel, sum, sumifs

I have a dataset that looks like this...

```
Group   Opportunity   Close Date    Stage   Yr Credited Probability Adjusted Credit
    Sigma   A           12/31/2016  Lost    2016          0.1
    Alpha   B           1/1/2016    Signed  2016          0.5
    Beta    C           7/26/2016   Review  2016          0.7
    Sigma   D - Loss    1/1/2016    Lost    2016          -1
    Alpha   E           12/31/2016  Review  2016          0.7
    Beta    F           1/25/2016   Pending 2016          0.6
    Sigma   G           12/31/2016  Review  2016          0.4
    Alpha   H           4/6/2014    Expired 2015          0.9
    Beta    I           5/14/2015   Pending 2015          0.1
    Sigma   J           12/31/2016  Review  2016          0.7
    Alpha   K - Loss    2/3/2016    Lost    2016          -0.5
    Beta    L           12/31/2016  Expired 2016          0.8
    Sigma   M           1/25/2016   Expired 2016          0.6
    Alpha   N           12/31/2016  Pending 2016          0.5
    Beta    O           12/31/2016  Pending 2016          0.4
    Sigma   P           12/31/2016  Pending 2016          0.3
```

Part of my goal is to us a SUMIFS function with an AND and OR statement. The formula should yield the sum of probability adjusted credits per Group if the following condition is met: Stage = Review OR BOTH Stage = Lost AND Opportunity contains "Loss"

The formula must function like a SUMIFS formula because I have other criteria to incorporate. However, this part of the criteria is not as straight forward to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternate [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff) for individual groups.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH("zzz",A:A ))=H2)*
                 SIGN((D$2:INDEX(D:D, MATCH("zzz",A:A ))="review")+
                 (D$2:INDEX(D:D, MATCH("zzz",A:A ))="lost")*
                 (RIGHT(B$2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH("zzz",A:A )), 4)="loss")),
             F$2:INDEX(F:F, MATCH("zzz",A:A )))
```

You can keep the line feeds in that formula if it helps you to make sense of it.

[image: alpha_beta_sigma]

The SUMPRODUCT function does not play well with AND / OR functions. Use + for OR and * for AND with appropriate bracketing to provide hierarchy.

---

Answer (score 3):

Use SUMPRODUCT():

```
=SUMPRODUCT((($D$2:$D$50 = "Review")+(($D$2:$D$50 = "Lost")*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Loss",$B$2:$B$50))))>0)*($F$2:$F$50))
```

[image]

When using Array formulas for `AND` and `OR` use the operands `*` and `+` respectively.

Edit:

Added the grouping:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((($D$2:$D$50 = "Review")+(($D$2:$D$50 = "Lost")*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Loss",$B$2:$B$50))))>0)*($F$2:$F$50)*($A$2:$A$50=H2))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm getting an error message when I try that formula.

Comment: @sqlbg I promise I did not photoshop the picture.  If you are getting errors there is a chance that your data is not uniform, as in there is text where there should be numbers and/or errors like `#N/A` in the data.

Comment: That's bizarre because I'm getting #VALUE! while using the same data that I posted originally.

Comment: @sqlbg try Jeeped's solution, I missed that you wanted it by group.  See if his works.

Comment: @ScottCraner I never thought of using + inside the sumproduct for an OR operation, I always repeated the sumproduct with the other option and added it to the first sumproduct.  I will try to remember to place it inside in the future as it seems much cleaner.